# Scrape data from local HTML file

Tags: c#, html, parsing, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the values for Design Capacity mWh and Full Charged Capacity mWh from windows battery-report.html  the HTML document stores these values in a table but with no attribute name I can easily access
I do have AngleSharp added but don't have much idea how to use it in this case to get the data I need it may not be right for the job though.

```
  </td>
</tr></thead>
<tr>
   <td><span class="label">NAME</span></td>
   <td>Blade</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><span class="label">MANUFACTURER</span></td>
   <td>Razer</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><span class="label">SERIAL NUMBER</span></td>
   <td>CNB1RC30-027097A00283-A05</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><span class="label">CHEMISTRY</span></td>
   <td>Li-I</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><span class="label">DESIGN CAPACITY</span></td>
   <td>65,003 mWh
   </td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:0.4em;"></tr>
<tr>
   <td><span class="label">FULL CHARGE CAPACITY</span></td>
   <td>72,395 mWh
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><span class="label">CYCLE COUNT</span></td>
   <td>
```

I generate the battery report and pass that togetBattery

```
private void BatteryHealthBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string designCap = null;
        string fullCap = null;
        ManagementObjectSearcher mybatteryObject = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_Battery");
        foreach (ManagementObject obj in mybatteryObject.Get())
        {
            if (obj["DesignCapacity"] != null || obj["FullChargeCapacity"] != null)
            {
                designCapTxt.Text = obj["DesignCapacity"].ToString();
                fullCapTxt.Text = obj["FullChargeCapacity"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No WMI Data Found Running Manually", "Error No WMI",
             MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                var saveLocation = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "battery-report.html";
                if (saveLocation != null)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                    startInfo.Arguments = "/C powercfg /batteryreport /output " + '"' + saveLocation + '"';
                    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    process.Start();
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(saveLocation);

                    GetBattery(saveLocation);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[Image of the Hmtl Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rBGO.png)

```
public async void GetBattery(string html)
    {
        var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
        string address = html;

        IDocument document = await
        BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(address);

        var designCap = document.GetElementsByClassName("label");
        
        MessageBox.Show(designCap.ToString(), "a",
             MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
```

think i am getting closer with this but getting null reference still on line 4

```
var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
        var address = html;
        var document = await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(address);
        var cellSelector = "tr td:nth-child(2)";
        var cells = document.QuerySelectorAll(cellSelector);
        var designCap = cells.Select(m => m.TextContent);
```

Comment: maeby i did not ask my question right. i have added my current csharp code too but i just have no idea what i need to be searching for. as any tag ive tried returns null

Comment: I am seeing a `BrowsingContext` class. What library/API is this? Is it a requirement to find a solution using this specific library?

Comment: i am using anglesharp and no its not but this is what ive tried open to other solutions                                                                                             
     using AngleSharp.Html.Parser;
using AngleSharp;
using AngleSharp.Dom;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to swap over to html agility pack but i got it

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                    // There are various options, set as needed
                    htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
                    // filePath is a path to a file containing the html
                    htmlDoc.Load(saveLocation);
                    foreach (HtmlNode table in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
                    {
                        foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
                        {
                            if(row.InnerText.Contains("DESIGN CAPACITY"))
                            {
                                designCapTxt.Text = row.InnerText;
                            }
                            if (row.InnerText.Contains("FULL CHARGE CAPACITY"))
                            {
                                fullCapTxt.Text = row.InnerText;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```